# Laravel 4: How to give/return response without ending PHP code?

Tags: php, excel, laravel-4, response

This is what I tried to achieve (without `AJAX` help):

I tried to input data from number of rows of an Excel file using Laravel's package `Maatwebsite/Excel` like this (see comment for what I'm trying to say):

```
\Excel::load($data['tmp_name'], function ($reader) use($data) {

            $eData = $reader->get();

            foreach ($eData as $e)
            {

                // after process row and save, i want to return a response and continue to next row
            }

        });
```

The reason I tried that approach is to be able to show user how many rows of data have been processe, so if there are 100 rows I can display something like "55 out of 100 data has been processed".

Is there any way to achieve this in Laravel?

Comment: This question displays a fundemental lack of understanding of how servers and websites work.  you can't send website headers more than once, to do what what you want you will have to use a web-socket, not AJAX.

Comment: Adding to @RaggaMuffin-420, server-sent events could also be an option worth researching.

Comment: @RaggaMuffin-420: i did write 'without AJAX', and is there any solution in the web-socket way (just a sample of it is enough, thank you for your help)?

Comment: just go and read about web-sockets.. you will need to create a socket-server and then JS has built in web-socket support.

Comment: If the only thing you need is to send the percentage, I would create (and overwrite) a text file containing number and `setTimeout` in JS to read the value from it. Web-sockets looks like overkill here.

Comment: @mudasobwa: text files (i forgot about that), might work, I'm currently using Laravel `Queue` but doesn't seem to work as expected, i will try your solution, thanks :)